# How to split a varchar column as multiple values in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have this SQL Select Statement

```
SELECT 
  AD_Ref_List.Value
FROM AD_Ref_List
WHERE AD_Ref_List.AD_Reference_ID= 1000448
```

This is the result of SELECT:

[image]

To limit the selected rows, I have a couple of values stored in other table like this:

```
SELECT xx_insert.XX_DocAction_Next
  FROM xx_insert
  WHERE xx_insert_id = 1000283
```

[image]

So, My final SQL Select is this:

```
SELECT 
  AD_Ref_List.Value
FROM AD_Ref_List
WHERE AD_Ref_List.AD_Reference_ID= 1000448
AND AD_Ref_List.Value           IN
  (SELECT xx_insert.XX_DocAction_Next
  FROM xx_insert
  WHERE xx_insert_id = 1000283
  )
;
```

PROBLEM : This SELECT return no line, because Oracle has transformed like this:  `AD_Ref_List.Value IN ('CO,VO')`

But, what I need is : `AD_Ref_List.Value IN ('CO','VO')`

How can I do this???

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the value in the delimiter you are using in the delimited list and then check if it is a sub-string of the delimited list (also with the delimiters wrapped around it):

```
SELECT r.Value
FROM   AD_Ref_List r
       INNER JOIN xx_insert x
       ON ( ',' || x.XX_DocAction_Next || ',' LIKE '%,' || r.value || ',%' )
WHERE  r.AD_Reference_ID = 1000448
AND    x.xx_insert_id    = 1000283;
```

> i must keep the logic in the whereClause

Really, don't. The above query will be much more efficient.

But if you have to then:

```
SELECT Value
FROM   AD_Ref_List
WHERE  AD_Reference_ID = 1000448
AND    value IN (
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( XX_DocAction_Next, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
  FROM   xx_insert
  WHERE  xx_insert_id    = 1000283
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( XX_DocAction_Next, '[^,]+' )
);
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your response, but i must keep the logic in the whereClause, like this : SELECT somColumns FROM MyTable WHERE myWhereClause AND AD_Ref_List.Value  IN

Comment: thanks, this is what i want, the request is auto-generated (i cant add only the last part) cause that i say that i must keep the order

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
SELECT l.value
  FROM ad_ref_list l INNER JOIN xx_insert xx
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(a.value, '^(' || REPLACE(xx.xx_docaction_Next, ',', '|') || '$' )      
 WHERE l.ad_reference_id = 1000448
   AND xx.xx_insert_id = 1000283;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If `xx.docaction_next` contains any special regular expression characters then either the regular expression will be invalid or may have unexpected behaviour.